# Javascript: Fade in and out

Tags: javascript, function, animation, fade

i have this PHP based doc (chatbox) where you can type your message and send it.

Now, i have this fade animation where a message comes in when a message is send. Looks like this:

Javascript:

```
function stateChanged1() 
{ 
if (xmlHttp1.readyState==4)
{ 
document.getElementById("sent").innerHTML="Sent!";
document.writeform.message.value="";
chat();
}
}
```

in the body:

```
<span id="sent"></span>
```

The problem is then it isnt fading out. What do i have to add to the code and where?

Comment: Where is your 'fading out' code? There is nothing to do with fading in the posted snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to your HTML and add this JavaScript Code:

```
$("#sent").fadeOut("slow");
```

after this line:

```
document.getElementById("sent").innerHTML="Sent!";
```

Comment: Works. but for slow it is going quite fast. And the weird thing of my code is also that if i send a message again, it won't display the 'Sent!' text again. Do you need some kind of extra script for it?

Comment: To show up the "Send!" message again use $("#sent").fadeIn("fast");

Comment: Maybe before document.getElementById("sent").innerHTML="Sent!"; ?

Comment: Super old, but for those finding this, you can set milliseconds as well as one of the parameters. http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 5):

For Effects like fading out use a framework like [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com), [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) or [MooTools](http://www.mootools.net).
They will provide you with ample examples how to apply effects to elements.

Comment: +1 For mentioning the various frameworks available to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

try jquery you can fadein and fade out an element easly e.i:

```
$("#sent").fadeIn("slow");
$("#sent").fadeOut("slow");
```

Answer (score 1):

i also recommend that you should use jquery's fade in and fade out function.
for a deeper explanation and code samples please goto: http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeOut